# How to loop through cursor where each iteration is a button click?

Tags: android, sqlite, loops

I am working on a quiz app of sorts. In one section I receive a cursor back from my sqlite DB.
It contains the ID for a question, and the order of the question.
I want to build a quiz activity based on this data by linking the question ID to the sql with a query once I figure out this loop.

Basically I want to be able to build an activity for the first question based on its cursor position and its order number variable(1,2,3, etc). and each time they answer a question and click the button it will iterate the loop and go onto the next cursor item and order number(question).

I am stuck on how to accomplish this.

```
Cursor questionID_query = dbHelper.getQuestionIDListFromChapterID(chapter_id);
```

I know I have to loop somehow, based on the cursors count.

```
for(int i=0; i < questionID_query.getCount(); i++){
    // loop through cursor
    //build question list
    //listen for button click
}
```

Basically any tips on how to accomplish this would be very nice, I am burnt out.

Answer (score 0):

**Best approach that I think and working like charm.**

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> readRowSQL(String rawSQL, String[] rawSQLSelectionArguments) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Cursor cursor = this.db.rawQuery(rawSQL, rawSQLSelectionArguments);
        this.colCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
        this.rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> col = new HashMap<String, String>();
                int size =cursor.getColumnCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    col.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
                }
                list.add(col);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

When you are returning cursor then first do this before returning:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

now in activity when cursor is returned to you then get the question from cursor and set to textviews and all. and after setting this to textviews just move the cursor to next question like:

```
cursor.moveToNext();
```

So when you click button for next just get value from cursor and then again make it to move next. so that you can get next question each time you click on button.

so its like:

in onCreate() method get Cursor

```
Cursor questionID_query = dbHelper.getQuestionIDListFromChapterID(chapter_id);
questionID_query.moveToFIrst();
txtQuestion.settext(questionID_query.getString(QuestionColumnNo));
questionID_query.moveToNext();
```

and in ButtonClick event:

```
txtQuestion.settext(questionID_query.getString(QuestionColumnNo));
questionID_query.moveToNext();
```

Hope it Helps!!